# ZKUI sorting by 'id' and not column

Tags: sorting, grails, zk, grails-2.1, zk-grid

I am a zkui newbie and I have a Listmodel with live data. There is a sorting attribute that is set on the view which should sort the data by the column clicked but actually sorts by the id- **sort="auto"**.
I found it at [this](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/listbox/auto_sort) site

Here is some sample code extracted from the site:

```
<columns menupopup="auto">
    <column label="Author" sort="auto" />
    <column label="Title" sort="auto" />
    <column label="Publisher" sort="auto" />
    <column label="Hardcover" />
</columns>
<rows>
    <row>
        <label value="Philip Hensher" />
        <label value="The Northern Clemency" />
        <label value="Knopf (October 30, 2008)" />
        <label value="608 pages" />
    </row>
<rows>
```

I researched a solution but I only found similar unanswered questions like the one [here](https://github.com/xiaochong/zkui/issues/43)

I wonder if the issue might be the fact that I'm working with live data.
Please tell me what to do to ensure that the data is sorted according to the clicked column.

I am using grails to develop the application and this is my list.gsp:

```
  <z:grid id="grid"
        emptyMessage="${message(code:'emptyMessage',default:'No Record')}">
        <z:columns sizable="true">
            <z:column
                label="${message(code: 'app.name.label', default: 'Name')}" sort="auto" />
            <z:column
                label="${message(code: 'app.status.label', default: 'Status')}" sort="auto"/>
```

Comment: this framework is very unpopular, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

In your list.gsp, try specifying the object attribute to be used in the sorting, like sort="auto(app.id)", sort="auto(app.name)" or whatever.